# Ajax POST request from JS to PHP does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The idea of ​​the code I'm trying to run is this: When a `$ _GET []` request arrives on the `products.php` page, I pass it via an ajax POST request to the `get_data_products.php` page and get data from there.

**PHP**

```php
 if(isset($_GET['cat'])){
   $filter_cat = $_GET['cat'];
   
   echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$filter_cat.'" class="getcat" />';
 }
```

**JS**

```js
 function filter_data2() {
     $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
     var action = 'fetch_data';
     var filter = [];
     var category = $('.getcat').val();
     filter.push(category);

       $.ajax({
           url:"<?php echo $g['url']; ?>get_date_products.php",
           method:"POST",
           data:{action:action,category:filter},
           success:function(data){
               $('.filter_data').html(data);
           }
       });
 }
```

The problem is: When I get for example `$_GET['category'] = 2` and ajax sends the data to `get_data_products.php` and then selects another category and `$_GET['category'] = 12` **sometimes it is not sent.**
When I give `var_dump` (`$_GET['category']`) it always contains the correct value, but for some reason ajax does not send it.

Comment: You're reading `$_GET['cat']` in PHP, while POSTing the request ..?

Comment: Hello ! No, I reading `$_GET['category']` and after this send with ajax to get_data_products.php and then reading `$_POST['category']`

Comment: That's what you've written in the question ...

Comment: No, sorry: products.php get $_GET['category'] and after this with ajax send it to get_data_products.php.

Comment: Try adding event.preventDefault(); before making your ajax request

Answer (score 0):

I can see a typo here url:"get_**date**_products.php" doesn't it supposed to be data?